# My table view works on my localhost, but not on Go-daddy's server

Tags: php, mysql, tableview

My table view works on my localhost, but not on Go-daddy's server returning empty result. Please see my codes below. Perhaps someone may have experience this scenario.

```
 include 'inc/db.php';

$sql="select * from table_view where status=1 and posted_date between '".$from."' and '".$to."' and user_id =? order by posted_date";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$user_id);
$stmt>bind_result($id,$user_id,$school_year,$posted_date,$wfpd,$sgpd,$planning,$modeling,$coaching,$ctc,$student_assmnt,$data_rprtng,$data_analysis,$meeting,$knowledge_bldg,$managing_rdng_mtrls,$mtss,$intervention,$bus,$lunch,$teaching,$sub,$misc,$status);
$stmt->execute();

 while($stmt->fetch()){?>

    <!--Display table here....-->

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Is it a table? or a view? If it is a view then you will have to create that view on your hosted database, in this case on godaddy. then it should work.

Comment: It's a view and i did created it on go daddy's server

Comment: @Ryan...yes. However when i use this approach below, it worked. Maybe it's the prepared statement; at this point, i don't know.   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $row["wfpd"]}